# Is Java fully aware of the entire recursive method even if the condition is not met?

Tags: java, recursion, heap-memory

I would like to understand in very simple terms if Java reads beyond the condition if it's not met in a method, I know it does not execute the portion if the condition was not met? or does not even try to waste time reading that portion?

I have attached the code to this message for your viewing.

I initially thought when I ran the code, that I would see only one number: -1 and that's it, But it was listing all of the numbers backwards.

I understand why they are coming out backwards from the Java Stack. So, obviously, there's a good number of recursive calls on the Java Stack (excuse me if said it wrong.)

But in my mind, that can only if Java interpreted/read the whole entire method at every recursion, executed the whole ENTIRE code every time, and saved the value of *n*, but chose not to output the result or put it on hold (but already has executed it behind the scene).

Thank you all, 
Can't wait to read your answers.

P.S. I am a Java student, and I am currently learning about Java Structures. So the easier your words the better I'll understand you. But I am thankful regardless of any attempts to help me.

```
public class Recursion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        reduceByOne(10);

    }

    public static void reduceByOne(int n) {
        if(n >= 0) {
            reduceByOne(n-1);
        }

        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: What? Recursive or not doesn't matter, the print is neither in an if nor in the else of the previous if so it executes always.

Comment: If the condition is not met the code is ignored. Java does not process it. I know this because obfuscators take advantage of this by adding nonsense code inside if conditions which are never met. I strongly suggest debugging you code line by line. It's the best way to learn

Comment: tkausi, thank you. But at line reduce(n-1): doesn't java jump right back up to the methods, hence ignoring the rest of the code?

Comment: "I initially thought when I ran the code, that I would see only one number: -1 and thats it, But it was listing all of the numbers backwards." Yes, because you call the method multiple times, and print once on every method call

Comment: Both commenters above actually answered the question. (@tkausl @dustytrash).  I'll just add a known practice to avoid null pointer exceptions by placing the questioned null object in the ignored section.  E.g:  if (obj != null && obj.equals("SomethingElse") )  { ... }  the equals of obj will be considered and executed only if obj is not null...

Comment: thank you @GBlodgett . I am sorry if my question wasn't clear, I want to know if Java ignores the remaining code in the method if a recursive call is made inside the method.

Comment: `doesn't java jump right back up to the methods, hence ignoring the rest of the code?` No, why would it? You couldn't have more than a single function call in a function if Java would do that... I don't really understand why people are that confused by recursive functions. Its just like any other function. You call it, it eventually returns, and it continues where it left off.

Comment: "Java ignores the remaining code in the method if a recursive call is made inside the method"
No it doesn't. That's exactly the reason you see multiple outputs - nothing is ignored. This code works in Java just like it would work in JavaScript, or BASIC, or Python or even Turbo Pascal. You don't seem to understand recursive method calls - there's nothing here special to Java at all.

Comment: Got it Everyone. Thank you @mvmn :) I really appreciate. You can ignore the comment I made below your answer. Clearest answer I've gotten, honestly I had a feeling I had the answer all along but I just need some clarity and assurance. Java is the only programming language I know by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the question here. Everything is pretty obvious. Let's go over it step by step. In order to shorten things let's imagine we call `reduceByOne(1)` from main instead of `reduceByOne(10)`.

- main method is called and it calls reduceByOne with n==1
- reduceByOne is called with n==1, if statement checks n and calls reduceByOne again (let's call it reduceByOne') with n'==0, thus
- reduceByOne' is called with n'==0, if statement checks n and calls reduceByOne'' with n''==-1, thus
- reduceByOne'' is called with n''==-1, if statement checks n and does nothing. Next line is println n'' which prints out -1. Then reduceByOne'' returns, which passes control back to reduceByOne'
- reduceByOne' continues after the if statement, prints n' which outputs 0 and returns, which passes control back to reduceByOne
- reduceByOne continues after the if statement, prints n which outputs 1 and returns, which passes control back to main method
- main method has no more lines and exists. JVM exits because main method has exited. The end.

P.S. Let's try to present the flow graphically:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    reduceByOne(1) => { // call of reduceByOne with n==1
        if( 1>=0 )  {
            reduceByOne(0) => { // call of reduceByOne' with n'==0
                if(0>=0) {
                    reduceByOne(-1) => { // call of reduceByOne'' with n''==-1
                        if(-1==0) // does nothing
                        System.out.println(-1)
                    } // return back to reduceByOne'
                }
                System.out.println(0)
            } // return back to reduceByOne
        }
        System.out.println(1);
    } // return back to main
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mvmn :) So when the recursion inside the method is invoked, doesn't java stop at that point to recall the method, like is java saying "Oh! so I am gonna stop here because I was asked to recall the method again NOW, so no need to read the rest of this code...until the condition is no longer met"  this is where I'm Stuck.

Comment: What do you mean "recall" method?

If you call method a inside which you call method b Java doesn't "stop", it just calls method b in the middle of method a. Same if you call method a from method a - you have a recursive call in the middle of a method. When that call returns the execution of the method will continue.

Comment: Just look at the call "diagram" I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Thanks again @mvmn I got. I get it now, the whole method is read and n is saved at every single recursion, so when the condition is met is now they can all pop off the stack. I appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, value of n is put on stack on every method call. That's what call stack is there for - to know where from method was called (to be able to return back when method is done) and what parameter values were passed to it. Primitive types like int are passed by value, so yes, actual values of n are put on stack on each recursive call. If this helps please mark my answer as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate your time. I got you I just made it the correct answer.

Comment: "The whole method is read" - that IMO is a confusing way to think of it. The instructions are just *sitting there* in memory. The computer is following instructions, generally sequentially but that is modified by loop statements, method calls, method returns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to understand assembly/machine code and how computers actually interpret the code you are writing.

This Java code you have written gets compiled (converted) into individual instructions for the machine to run. When function calls happen, they save the current state of the function that calls them (the caller) to the stack (values of variables). That way when the function returns that state can be brought back to how it was before.

In your example, when the `reduceByOne(n-1)` call happens, it saves the state of the current value of `n` to the stack and starts running the new invocation of the `reduceByOne()` function. After that function call finishes and returns back, the state is brought back to how it was before and it executes the next lines of code (printing out `n`).

Nothing is pre-read in other then it loads all the instructions for the program and then executes each instruction one at a time. Sometimes one line of code is converted into multiple instructions. This can be a bit different with multithreading/efficient processors, but for you example this is how the program is working.

Comment: Thank you so much @Karl I really want to learn and excited about learning about assembly coding. I have been programming for a 6 months, but so far I am so I like programming and hoping to expand my knowledge. So when the recursion inside the method is invoked, doesn't java stop at that point to recall the method, like is java saying "Oh! so I am gonna stop here because I was asked to recall the method again NOW, so no need to read the rest of this code..." this is where I'm Stuck.

Comment: Yes when the computer starts executing the `reduceByOne(n-1)` line it stops where it currently is at, saves its current state, and jumps to start executing that new function call. After that new function call finishes, the program resumes again from its saved state. I am not quite sure what you mean by "recall" the method though, it only know that you are making a function call. It doesn't matter if it's the same one again or a new function.